Clarification on Timestamp Conversion for Motive Data Transfer to ROS VRPN Node
I am currently working on a project where I am sending data from OptiTrack Motive (running on a Windows PC) to a ROS VRPN Client node on an Ubuntu PC. I am conducting two experiments:
Using server-side timestamps (from Motive).
Using the timestamps received on the ROS node side.
I am encountering a problem with the server-side timestamps. The timestamp values I receive from Motive are as follows:

2445995.247859
2445995.265
2445995.281

These correspond to dates in 1970, specifically around January 29, 1970, 07:26:35 (UTC). Based on my understanding, these timestamps might be in a different format, and I need help converting them to proper UNIX timestamps or ensuring they reflect the current time.
Could you provide guidance on how to resolve this and obtain correct timestamps for further processing in ROS?
Thank you for your kind assistance.
